# Ошибка с System.Management

Tags: c#, using

Всех приветствую. Возможно проблема банальна, но в c# недавно. При подключении `using System.Management;`
вылезает следущее: см скрин. Дайте решение проблемы, либо дайте ссылку на статьи с решением. Буду крайне благодарен :D
[image: Скрин ошибки]

Comment: Какой целевой фреймворк в cproj файле?

Comment: @aepot WPF приложение

Comment: .NET Framework 4.x или .NET Core 3.1 или .NET 5 или что-то другое?

Comment: Вам решение на скрине показано, желтая лампа, жмите на нее и там будет подключение к проекту нужной dll, либо скачивание ее через NuGet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам уже дали набросок решения.

Если у Вас .NetFramework - то по лампочке система предложит поставить нужную ссылку

Если у Вас .NetCore- то по лампочке система предложит поставить Nuget пакет (в Core все перевели в пакеты)

Читайте комментарии и дополняйте вопрос своевременно или Вам не смогут помочь